# Unable to retrieve whole data on acknowledge in socket.IO [iOS]

Tags: ios, objective-c, socket.io

I'm developing an iOS application which uses this library https://github.com/pkyeck/socket.IO-objc to connect to a socket.IO server. I'm able to connect and send messages but I can't retrieve the whole data eventhough I can see the data in a message debug.

For example, I'm using this code:

```
SocketIOCallback cb = ^(id argsData) {
    NSDictionary *response = argsData;
};
[socketIO sendEvent:@"welcomeAck" withData:dict andAcknowledge:cb];
```

If I print the `response` dictionary I will only get the success value but not the rest.
However in the debug window I can read the whole data:

```
2015-04-08 16:52:16.731 AppSocketTry[43569:628029] onData 6:::1+["success",{"streams":[],"socketId":"YtBgH8iSoVhDKHyoRPtX","id":"552540e743c3ffa944ddb852"}]
```

Is there any way to retrieve the whole data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is setting this property:

```
self.socket.returnAllDataFromAck = YES;
```